# Forked Processes When Rsyncing via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, openssh

I'm having an issue where when I try to send a file to my remote web server via `rsync` on my Linux OS, I receive the following error message:

```
/etc/profile.d/locallib.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/etc/profile.d/locallib.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/etc/profile.d/locallib.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/etc/profile.d/locallib.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/etc/profile.d/locallib.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 254) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

**rsync Code**

```
rsync -vzhe ssh some.file user@remote.server:remote.dir/
```

Comment: You don’t need “ssh” when using rsync I believe

Comment: Your command is fine however you appear to be hitting a resource limit in your current shell session. Checkout this question for steps to further debug this issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205016/fork-retry-resource-temporarily-unavailable

Comment: Hi @pat, none of the solutions worked from that page

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not with rsync command, actual issue with remote server , unable to do ssh to remote server due to resources are exhausted from it.
Contact System Administrator in this case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).